Tensor product of two Group Representation
I have a question regarding the definition of tensor product of group representation. I found two definitions: One, is from Wikipedia. The other is from J. L. Loday's book Algebraic Operads. Please note that I don't know anything about representations of groups. Kindly, try to give an answer in simple terms, if possible. Let $G$ be a group and $\mathbb{K}$ be a field of characteristic zero.
Group Representation:
A representation of $G$, called as a left $G$-module, is a vector space $V$ together with a left action $\cdot : \mathbb{K}[G] \times V \to V$ which satisfies the following properties:
\begin{align*}
 &\text{Distributivity:}\quad 
 g \cdot (v + w) ~=~ g \cdot v + g \cdot w \quad \text{and} 
    \quad (g + h) \cdot v ~=~ g \cdot v  + h \cdot v \\
 &\text{Scalar compatibility:} \quad 
 k (g \cdot v) ~=~ (kg) \cdot v ~=~ g \cdot (kv) \\
 &\text{Group compatibility:} \quad 
 (gh) \cdot v ~=~ g \cdot (h \cdot v) 
 \quad \text{and} \quad 
 1_{\mathbb{K}[G]} \cdot v ~=~ v.     
\end{align*}
for all $v \in V,~ k \in \mathbb{K}$, and $g,h \in G$. Here $\mathbb{K}[G]$ denotes the group algebra of $G$ over $\mathbb{K}$.
Note: Similarly we have the notion of a right $G$-module. And since $\mathbb{K}[G]$, in general, is a non-commutative, unital, associative algebra, one can see $\mathbb{K}[G]$ as a non-commutative ring with unity.
Tensor Product of Group Representation (Wikipedia):
Let $M$ and $N$ be two left $G$-module. Then their tensor product, denoted by $M \otimes_G N$, is the tensor product of vector spaces $M \otimes N$ with left action $\cdot : \mathbb{K}[G] \times M \otimes N \to M \otimes N$ being defined as
$$g \cdot (m \otimes n) := (g \cdot m) \otimes (g \cdot n)$$
for all $g \in G$, $m \in M$, and $n \in N$. Then extending it linearly to whole $\mathbb{K}[G]$ and $M \otimes N$ defines the left action.
The distributivity of left action follows from its construction.
Question 1: How do we show scalar compatibility?
Since I think $k(g \cdot (m \otimes n)) \neq (kg) \cdot (m \otimes n)$, as shown in the computation below:
$$k(g \cdot (m \otimes n)) = k (g \cdot m \otimes g \cdot n) \neq k(g \cdot m) \otimes k(g \cdot n) = (kg) \cdot (m \otimes n)$$
There is a similar question Tensor Product of Two Group Representations (Action Well-definedness), but the answer there doesn't discuss scalar compatibility.
Tensor Product of Group Representation (J. L. Loday):
Let $M$ be a right $G$-module and $N$ be a left $G$-module. Then $M$ can be seen as a right $\mathbb{K}[G]$ module and $N$ as a left $\mathbb{K}[G]$ module (considering $\mathbb{K}[G]$) as a ring). Then their tensor product over the ring $\mathbb{K}[G]$ is the abelian group $M \otimes_{\mathbb{K}[G]} N$.
Question 2: But how do we turn it into a $G$-module (left or right)?
Question 3:  Do these definitions have any relation between them?
Edit 1:
Vector Space structure on the tensor product of group representation (J. L. Loday): Following the answer provided by Qiaochu Yuan I am trying to define a vector space structure on $M \otimes_{\mathbb{K}[G]} N$ in the following way: since $M$ and $N$ are vector spaces over $\mathbb{K}$, the abelian group
\begin{equation*}
  M \otimes_G N := M \otimes_{\mathbb{K}[G]} N \Big/ \Big\langle 
    \{km \otimes n - m \otimes kn: k \in \mathbb{K}, m \in M, n \in N 
    \}\Big\rangle
\end{equation*}
turns into a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$, with scalar multiplication being defined as follows:
$$k (m \otimes n) := km \otimes n ~=~ m \otimes kn.$$
Question 4: Is the construction fine?
Induced Representation (J. L. Loday): (Algebraic Operads, Appendix A.2, pg 458)
Loday gave the following definition of induced representation of a group $G$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $M$ be a right $H$-module. Then one can construct a representation of $G$ (, i.e., a left $G$-module) called the induced representation of $G$, which is defined as
\begin{equation}
 \mathrm{Ind}^G_H(M) := M \otimes_H \mathbb{K}[G]
\end{equation}
where $\mathbb{K}[G]$ is viewed as a left $H$-module through multiplication in $\mathbb{K}[G]$.
Question 5: Following the above vector space construction. We have that $\mathrm{Ind}^G_H(M)$ is a vector space. But how do I make it a left $G$-module?
Edit 2:
Following Qiaochu Yuan's second comment, I am trying to give a correct description of the tensor product of two group representations.
Let $V$ be a right $G$-module and $W$ be a left $G$-module. The tensor product of $V$ and $W$ is a vector space
\begin{equation*}
  V \otimes_G W := V \otimes W \Big/ \Big\langle \{m \cdot g 
    \otimes n - m \otimes g \cdot n: g \in G, m \in M, n \in 
    N\}\Big\rangle
\end{equation*}
over $\mathbb{K}$, where $V \otimes W$ is the vector space tensor product of $V$ and $W$. Thus, generators of $V \otimes_G W$ satisfies the following identities:
\begin{align*}
    (v_1 + v_2) \otimes w = v_1 \otimes w + v_2 \otimes w, &\quad v 
    \otimes (w_1 \otimes w_2) ~=~ v \otimes w_1 + v \otimes w_2, \\
  k (v \otimes w) ~=~ kv \otimes w ~=~ v \otimes kw, &\quad (v   
    \cdot g) \otimes w ~=~ v \otimes (g \cdot w),  
\end{align*}
for all $v,v_1,v_2 \in V$; $w,w_1,w_2 \in W$; $k \in \mathbb{K}$; $g \in G$.
Furthermore, $V \otimes_G W$ can be viewed as a left or right $G$-module, with the following left action $ \cdot: \mathbb{K}[G] \otimes V \otimes_G W \to V \otimes_G W$ being defined as
\begin{equation*}
    g \cdot (v \otimes w) := v \otimes g \cdot w
\end{equation*}
for all $g \in G$, $v \in V$, and $w \in W$. Then extending it to the whole of $\mathbb{K}[G]$ and $V \otimes_G W$ linearly we get the left action which makes $V \otimes_G W$ a left $G$ module. Similarly, the right action is defined by  $(v \otimes w) \cdot g := v \cdot g \otimes w$.
Edit 3:
As Qiaochu Yuan pointed out in the comments that in general $V \otimes_G W$ is not a $G$-module. But if $V$ is a right $G$-module and $W$ is both a left and right $G$-module. Then $V \otimes_G W$ becomes a right $G$-module via the right action $\cdot: V \otimes_G W \otimes \mathbb{K}[G] \to V \otimes_G W$ defined as
$$(v \otimes w) \cdot g := v \otimes w \cdot g$$

These are just two different operations. By default, "tensor product of representations of a group" refers to the first one. The second one is used to define group homology (edit: ah, and also induced representations, as you mention), and it is only a $K$-vector space and doesn't have an action of $G$ on it.
There is no issue with compatibility with scalars. The definition of the action of $G$ on the tensor product only applies to elements of $G$, it's not supposed to apply to elements of $K[G]$. The extension to elements of $K[G]$ is by linearity, so we have
$$k(g(m \otimes n)) = k(gm \otimes gn) = (kgm) \otimes gn = gm \otimes (kgn) = (kg)(m \otimes n).$$
Edit: The first equation of your edit is not correct but yes, the vector space structure on $M \otimes_{K[G]} N$ is just the obvious one, $k(m \otimes n) = km \otimes n = m \otimes kn$.
I have no idea why Loday is working with right $H$-modules. Normally representations refer to left $H$-modules, in which case induction should be defined via a tensor product on the left, as
$$\text{Ind}_H^G(M) = K[G] \otimes_{K[H]} M.$$
Then the left $G$-module structure comes from the left $G$-module structure on $K[G]$.
Generally speaking I think you should not be trying to learn representation theory of groups from Loday, since that isn't the focus of the book anyway.

Following your answer I have edited my post, by trying to add a vector space structure on the tensor product as defined by Loday. But this raises another question which I have added at the end of my post. Please, have a look at it, if possible.

@Saikat: I've edited in responses. Generally it's considered bad form to edit a question like this after someone's already answered it. Better to ask a new question, usually.

You mentioned the first equation in my edit is not correct. But without that can we tell $km \otimes n = m \otimes kn$?

@Saikat: your equation is incorrect because you have $M \otimes_G N$ on the left hand side (which is irrelevant), $M \otimes_{K[G]} N$ on the RHS (shouldn't it be on the LHS?), and you quotient by a subspace which is already zero. The definition of the tensor product over $K[G]$ already implies $km \otimes n = m \otimes kn$ in $M \otimes_{K[G]} N$.

As you mentioned that, the first equation in "Edit 1" is incorrect. I have tried to fix it in "Edit 2". Please let me know if that is correct. I also think that $M \otimes_G N$ becomes a left $G$-module, I have provided my arguments in "Edit 2". But since you have already mentioned that $M \otimes_G N$ is only a vector space and has no $G$ action. I am making a mistake. Can you kindly point the mistake out?

@Saikat: you did not check that this was a $G$-action! With your definition we have $gh (m \otimes n) = m \otimes ghn = mg \otimes hn = h(mg \otimes n) = h(m \otimes gn) = m \otimes hgn$ - note that the order of $g$ and $h$ have been swapped. So this doesn't work as a definition unless $G$ is abelian, in which case we recover the familiar $R$-modules structure on a tensor product of modules over a commutative ring $R$.

I understand the problem now. But in the case of induced representation how do we get a action of $G$ on $M \otimes_H \mathbb{K}[G]$? We should get the same problem you mentioned in the above comment there as well. Right? And is the first equation mentioned in "Edit 2" fine now?

@Saikat: in that case the action of $G$ is defined by multiplication on the right so there's no issue. The idea is that the tensor product "uses up" one side of the module structure but here there is a module structure on both sides. The general pattern is the following: if $M$ is a right $R$-module and $N$ is an $(R, S)$-bimodule, then the tensor product $M \otimes_R N$ is a right $S$-module. Here $K[G]$ is a $(K[H], K[G])$-bimodule.

And yes, the first equation in edit 2 is fine now. This is admittedly confusing stuff, authors rarely make the bimodule structure explicit.
